# How to format a Javascript Object Reference to use a custom parameter, which uses a macro like so #macro#?

Tags: javascript, object, macros

I'm trying to implement an image uploader widget from 2imgs.com, that would allow users on my website to upload an image and get the direct image URL returned to a form textarea.

The way the object is defined in their API I can easily get back BBC code, an HTML link, etc... but I can also pass in a custom definition.  In their documentation, found here: http://www.2imgs.com/api ... they say this about their custom code:

cfgCustomCode
(string) custom template string for the target link and thumbnail; following macros may be used:
 #show# - URL of (link to) full image

I just don't know how to format the parameter!  More to the point, I don't really know what they mean by 'macro' here.  I've tried passing it in like 'custom#show#', 'custom(#show#)', 'custom(show)' ... anyone who can explain why I'm doing it wrong will probably laugh at that and tell me why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help from a buddy.  cfgCustomCode is a variable that needs to be set on the object after initialization.  Like so:

```
var o2i = new upload2i('button_2i_div', 'videos', 'en', 'custom');
o2i.cfgBackURLPath = '2i.html';
o2i.cfgCustomCode = '#show#';
```

Incidentally, this didn't spit out the hotlink I needed though... I'm gonna have to scrape for that.